# How to check DB2 installation in a Linux machine(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, db2

Is there any command or any way to list the DB2 instances in a Linux machine(specifically Ubuntu)? or else any way to find whether a Linux machine has DB2 installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To see all running db2instances.

ps -ef | grep db2sysc

2. db2ilist

Lists all the instances that are created using the db2icrt command from the same DB2® copy location that you are running the db2ilist command.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002059.html

3. You can also look for instance footprints. find something like the sqllib directory. Each instance has one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `db2level`. If there is a DB2 installed, usually you can get a message like the following:

```
$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "iidev20")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11015" with level identifier
"0206010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.0.0", "n1612141900", "DYN1612141900AMD64",
and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/home/iidev20/sqllib".
```

Comment: unless we logged in to the DB2 instance, we can't run db2level command. it is essential to run "sudo su - db2inst1" to log into DB2 command to "db2level". I want something which I can run without log into the db2 instance